# LINQ on complex nested observable collection

Tags: linq, nested, observablecollection

I have a nested `ObservableCollection<Student>`, from which how can I get a particular student based on Id value using LINQ or Lambda ? Here is my Student class:

```
public class Student
    {

        public Student()
        {

        }

        public string Name;
        public int ID;
        public ObservableCollection<Student> StudLists;
    }
```

So each student object can have again student collections and it can go like any number of nested levels. how we can do it LINQ or using Lambda ? I have tried with

```
var studs = StudCollections.Where(c => c.StudLists.Any(m => m.ID == 122));
```

But this is not giving exact Student item ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to search all descendants of StudCollections, then you could write an extension method like so:

```
static public class LinqExtensions
{
  static public IEnumerable<T> Descendants<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> DescendBy)
  {
    foreach (T value in source)
    {
        yield return value;

        foreach (T child in DescendBy(value).Descendants<T>(DescendBy))
        {
            yield return child;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

and use it like so:

```
var students = StudCollections.Descendants(s => s.StudLists).Where(s => s.ID == 122);
```

If you want one student with a matching id, use:

```
var student = StudCollections.Descendants(s => s.StudLists).FirstOrDefault(s => s.ID == 122);

if (student != null)
{
  // access student info here
}
```

Comment: Not only beat me to it, but with a better answer.  I like this.  Additionally for the OP's last sentence I think what he really wants is `First` or `Single` (or the `OrDefault` variants)

Comment: foreach (Student ss in students)
{
                
} // when i iterate though the students, it is throwing error in the method Descendants<T> in the extention class. the parameter Source in this method is null.

Comment: @coldwin then StudList is null on one of the student.  Unless there's a specific reason for it to be null, you should assign it to an empty list in the constructor.

Comment: Alternatively you can wrap the `foreach` loop in an `if (DescendBy(value) != null)`